# Schengen visa issued by France to Sweden

Tags: visas, schengen, sweden

I have a Schengen visa issued by the French embassy. My main trip is to France. But I have a sister (sister by heart, not by blood) who is Indonesian and had been living in Sweden for 3 years. I'm planning to visit her for two or three weeks, all cost such as accommodation and food will cover them. What do I need to be able to enter and stay in Sweden?

Do I need my friend to make an invitation or attestation letter for me?

Answer (score 3):

If your *main destination* is still what it was when you made your visa application, you can make whichever side trips within the Schengen area you want in addition to that main destination, as long as you don't exceed the visa's allowed length of stay.

You do not need any particular invitations or other formalities, but when you *initially enter* the Schengen area you should be prepared to explain your plans for the entire trip, and document it to the extent it is reasonably documentable. For example, you should have plans for where you will stay and plans for your travel between the various destinations.

Comment: Note that there may be problems if the initial application *appears* fraudulent because of major changes in the itinerary.

Comment: @o.m.: Hence the qualification that I'm assuming that the main destination is unchanged.

Comment: I was concerned that things *look* bad even if they are not. Say the submitted itinerary was 45 days France, the changed itinerary is 24 days France, 21 days Sweden. Even if France is still the main destination, such a change can hurt the credibility.